# Internet Explorer (IE) Issue: Content in one HTML Table column does not vertically align with the top of an adjacent Table column

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, browser

I'm running into a formatting issue that shows up in IE but not in Chrome, FireFox, or Safari.

**BACKGROUND:**
I built an HTML page that follows a pretty common structure of putting main controls along the top, navigation controls on the left, data/content views on the right, and a footer on the bottom of the page.

The different areas on the page are segmented using HTML Tables and Divs.

**PROBLEM/SYMPTOM:** The content in the left Navigation Controls area is not enough to span the vertical length of the data and information views in the section on the right.  Because of this, the content in the Navigation section, on the left, floats down to the middle, rather than staying anchored at the top.

**QUESTION:** How do I get the HTML content in the column on the left of a Table to vertically align at the top of the table, so it is appropriately aligned with the content in the right column, in such a manner that it works in IE as well as in all other browsers?  (Again, it already works fine in all browsers but IE, so the issue is really about how to fix it in IE.)

**Page Example 1:** http://nounz.if4it.com/Nouns/Applications/Dashboard.html

**Page Example 2:** http://nounz.if4it.com/index.html

**NOTE:** All HTML styles are in page.

It's driving me a bit nuts, at this point.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Frank

Comment: `td {vertical-align: top;}` ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response. Does the "td {vertical-align: top;}" need to be placed on both sides, in the event that the reverse happens (e.g. more content in the left Navigation column than in the right Data View column)?

Comment: I verified it and it works.  The only thing I want to add is that I had to ensure applying the vertical-align to both columns in the table, so that it guards against a mismatch in column size happening with either column and not just the one on the left.